# Explain The Purpose Of Overriding In This Code Please

Tags: java

This is My Sir's Code Below Can you Just Explain Why He have used The Override Methods? Its only one class I have copy pasted please explain it.

```
    package vehicle;

    enum carType{LUXURY,ELECTRIC,SPORTS}


    public abstract class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
        private int carId;
        private carType type;
        private float price;
        private String model;

        public Car(int carId, carType type, float price, String model) {
            this.carId = carId;
            this.type = type;
            this.price = price;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public int getCarId() {
            return carId;
        }

        public float getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Car{" + "carId=" + carId + ", type=" + type + ", price=" + price + ", model=" +
                    model + '}';
        }


          public boolean equals(Object obj)     
          {
              if(obj instanceof Car)
              {
                  Car c = (Car)obj;
              if(c.carId==carId)
                     return true;
              }

                     return false;
    }


        @Override
        public int compareTo(Car o) {

            if(carId>o.carId)
                 return 1;
             else if (carId<o.carId)
                 return -1;
             else 
                 return 0;
    }

    public abstract void display();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a student so my explanation may be not so accure but i think:

This part is overriden because there is a BUILT-IN ToString() method , so by using the @Override he tells the programm that when toString() is called he is supposed to use the one that you have created.

```
 @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Car{" + "carId=" + carId + ", type=" + type + ", price=" + price + ", model=" +
                    model + '}';
        }
```

Here we override the EQUALS method also provided in the BUILT-IN methods , so when you compare to objects the programm will know to use THAT PARTICULAR method(the one writen by you).

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)     
          {
              if(obj instanceof Car)
              {

              Car c = (Car)obj;
          if(c.carId==carId)
                 return true;
          }

                 return false;
}
```

Same reason here

```
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Car o) {

            if(carId>o.carId)
                 return 1;
             else if (carId<o.carId)
                 return -1;
             else 
                 return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Now i got the point why override is used, but what do you mean by BUILT IT tostring method

Comment: i would suggest you to try and comment out the given above override and : 1. create some object of the Car class,fill it with what ever data you want to.              2. call the toString(); see what you get.                             Then uncomment the toString() method and see what the difference is =).   he best way (in my personal opinion) is to see what differences occur when you do something in the code.

Comment: Good Idea. Ill Try That Way